# Trouble with masking

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking

I am trying to mask out a section of an image I created with an algorithm. I create a geometry of the section I want to mask out and clipped that with an image of 1's to create my mask image. But when I attempt to mask my original image it only clips the part I'm trying to remove rather than masking out the section and retaining the rest.

how can I remove the pixels from my mask and retain the rest of the image?

link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/844c40e72f98761c0bbe46a003989213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you need:

```js
var basemap = ee.ImageCollection([image5, image3]).max()
var buff = seam.buffer(14000)
var mask = ee.Image.constant(1).clip(buff).mask().not()
var newBasemap = basemap.updateMask(mask)
Map.addLayer(newBasemap, {}, 'newBasemap')
```

I also made a public function for that

```js
var tools = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:tools')
var basemap = ee.ImageCollection([image5, image3]).max()
var buff = seam.buffer(14000)
var newBasemap = tools.geometry.maskInside(basemap, buff)
Map.addLayer(newBasemap, {}, 'newBasemap')
```

link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/c08efa296c63ecbbe2107cf6e0129329